# Methods and arrays

Tags: java, arrays

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;


public class zadanko4
{
    int ile;

    public static final int vat8 = 8;
    public static final int vat23 = 23;
    public static final int vat5 = 5;

    //deklaracje zmiennych tablicowych
    static double[] price;
    static String[] name;
    static int[] quantity;
    static int[] vat;

    //tworzenie tablic
    price = new double[ile];
    name = new String[ile];
    quantity = new int[ile];
    vat = new int[ile];

    public static void printSellerData(String tekst)
    {
        System.out.print(tekst);
    }

    public static void printBuyerData(String company, String taxNo, String phone, String email)
    {
        System.out.print(company + taxNo + phone + email);
    }

    public static void printInvoiceDate(Date data)
    {

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        System.out.print(dateFormat.format(data));
    }

    public static void printInvoiceHeader(String naglowek)
    {
        System.out.print(naglowek);
    }

    public static void printInvoiceProduct(String name, int quantity, double price, int vat)
    {
        System.out.printf(name + quantity + price + vat);
    }

    public static void readProductsData()
    {
        //uzytkownik wprowadza liczbe produktow
        System.out.println("podaj liczbe produktow");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System. in );
        ile = scanner.nextInt();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int i;
        String line;

        for (i = 0; i < ile; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Podaj cene produktu nr " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            price[i] = scanner.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("Podaj nazwe produktu nr " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            name[i] = scanner.next();
            System.out.print("Podaj ilosc produktu nr " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            quantity[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Podaj vat produktu nr " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            vat[i] = scanner.nextInt();


            System.out.printf("Dane sprzedajacego\n");
            printSellerData("Company: MaxDom Ltd, Kochanowskiego 17, 31-782 Krakow, Poland\n");
            printSellerData("Tax no: 677-000-21-39\n");
            printSellerData("Phone: +48123454943\n");
            printSellerData("Email: office@maxdom.pl\n\n");

            System.out.printf("Dane kupujacego\n");
            printBuyerData("Softpol Ltd, Mickiewicza 5, 31-009 Krakow, Poland\n", "342-909-33-12\n", "+48505392100\n", "office@softpol.eu\n");
            //  printInvoiceNumber(+numer+);
            Date data = new Date();
            printInvoiceDate(data);
            printInvoiceHeader("|No.|Product desciptrion    |Quantity   |Unit price |Total  |VAT rate   |VAT    |Gross|");
            printInvoiceHeader("|______________________________________________________________________________________________________|");
            //printInvoiceProduct("name[i]", ilosc[prod], cena[prod], vat[prod]");
            printInvoiceProduct("|" + (i + 1) + "   |" + name[i] + "            |" + quantity[i] + "        |" + price[i] + "       |" + (quantity[i] * price[i]) + "   |" + (vat[i] / 100.0) + "           |" + (quantity[i] * price[i] * (vat[i] / 100.0)) + "    |" + (quantity[i] * price[i]) * (1 + (vat[i] / 100.0)));
        }
    }
}
```

and my problems:

1. I have 4 errors like:  `error: <identifier> expected`. It is connected
   with arrays but i have no idea what is wrong.
2. By the last line: printInvoiceProduct.... I want to display 1 product which user entered, but nothing displays.

Why is that?

Comment: good start would be to properly format the code...

Comment: showing the errors would be great.

Comment: ile has no value, so the array creation will fail. but there can be more of this

Comment: @MightyPork Formatting Done.

Comment: Needed some clarity on what you want.

Comment: thanks for formatting.
sorry, now i noticed thath i didnt translate into english whole text.
to the point: user enter name (of product), price, quantity and vat.
i want to display information of what user entered.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create new memory addresses for arrays as you refer them. Like;

   `static double[] price = new double[ile];`
2. This is also not enough because these static arrays trying to make a static reference to a non-static variable, "ile". So if you want your arrays to be *static*, just make "ile" static also.
3. `printInvoiceProduct` method is declared to pass 4 arguments to it but you've called it by only one String object.

Comment: thanks for help.
How to make "ile" static?
Something like this: price = new static double[ile]; ?
I do not get third point. What you mean by one Strin object? Which one?
Im sorry, I am a noob.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you solve compilation errors you will face again problems.
 For example you are creating an array with size zero This will fail. So instead of creating your array objects above; create in the main function after knowing size of array.
So get rid of ile variable. Take input in the main and then instantiate all the array. 
Even I don't see a need of class level arrays all can be method local.

On top of that I don't think this is correct platform to solve such problem. Consider putting your problem on

> https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: not really. I di not pasted whole code, but i have something like:
      System.out.println("enter number of products");
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  ile = scanner.nextInt();
And this all make size of array

Comment: That is not going to help because value ile will be accounted at the time of creation of array which you are doing at class level.